# angularfirebase2 query where key equals value

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm giving shot at firebase, converting an existing database to firebase. How do i select a list where the value of a key equals a specific value?

```
getAllUsers() {
    return this.fireBase.list(
        '/users',
        ref => ref
            .orderByChild('last_name')
            // active = true
    ).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to order by last name and then filter for a specific value of active (I.e. true)?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Firebase Realtime Database you cannot use `orderBy()` on one field and then use `equalTo()` on another field. And you cannot use two different `orderBy()`.

This is detailed/explained in the docs, [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md#invalid-query-combinations) (angularfire2
) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) ("standard" Javascript SDK).

However you could use a composed value like `active_lastname` with a query like the following one:

```
  var database = firebase.database();
  database
    .ref('users')
    .orderByChild('composedValue')
    .startAt('true_')
    .endAt('true_\uf8ff')
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childKey);
        console.log(childData);
      });
    });
```

You composed values would be like:

```
true_Obama
true_Bush
false_Carter
....
```

---

So for angularFire2, based on your code it would be:

```
getAllUsers() {
    return this.fireBase.list(
        '/users',
        ref => ref
            .orderByChild('composedValue')
            .startAt('true')
            .endAt('true\uf8ff')
    ).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks. i think it's more important for me to filter by the value, so i will handle the sorting by name on the client side.

Comment: Just note that the second part of my initial answer was wrong... You cannot reach your goal by using a composed values starting by the `last_name`. But you can achieve it with a composed value starting by the `active` value, see my updated answer.